# How can I call an action in application_controller.rb, without having a corresponding view file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I am trying click on a link to call this action.

```
<% link_to "popup", :action => 'user_logs_out', :controller => 'application'%>
```

In my application controller I have this action:

```
def user_logs_out
    gon.display_sign_out_popup = true
end
```

How can I call this action? It always shows template error. Since the action simply needs to set a boolean value, I don't feel a need to have view file for it.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of setting the popup variable in the action? You don't have to store server-side state for things like popup visibility. I have a strong suspicion that you're going down the wrong path with this.

Comment: I am intending to use gon gem, where gon.display_sign_out_popup = true will be set. Depending upon the boolean value of display_sign_out_popup of this javascript variable, my application.js responds with a pop-up. I hope I have explained you the secnario sufficiently

Comment: That's a tremendously round-about way of showing a popup. There is absolutely no reason to go to the server to simply set a variable which causes a dialog to popup. You should just bind an event handler to the link which shows the popup without the round trip to the server.

Comment: Oh... wait, I need to fetch & display some table values in the pop-up. so the method display_sign_out_popup  would eventually have, some values fetched from database.

Comment: point me to some resources, if there is a simple way to set a javascript variable a boolean value via click of a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want an action to render nothing, you can use [`render :nothing => true`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render).

```
def user_logs_out
  display_sign_out_popup = true
  render :nothing => true
end
```

However, there is almost certainly no reason why you would want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put

```
def user_logs_out
    display_sign_out_popup = true
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

You also must put `:remote => true` in your link_to

...and if you are trying to learn authentication from scratch I would recommend Hartl's free tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=3.2#cha-modeling_users

Comment: Actually, this is getting outta hand.. I'm out!